# Access denied in localhost phpmyadmin

Tags: server, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have xampp installed on my local machine which was working fine. Suddenly, im getting this error.[image]

I am sure it was working fine, but now i have important database in my localhost(i dont have backup)

I tried fixing the problem, but everytime i get this error

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Anyone help me to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance.